# Router Wi-Fi not working after power failure

Tags: router, netgear, tp-link

I know this sounds lame, but it's the second consumer router in as many months which has Wi-Fi issues after power failures. My electric utility company sent notices this morning that they were working on the power grid, and that we'll have outages today (this is my home). I unplugged the NAS and the computer, but didn't think to unplug the router. When I came back from work I found the router powered on, but my phone and laptop failed connecting to the WLAN ("invalid password"). The LAN works fine (I'm writing this using the desktop at home). I powered off the router completely for 30 minutes or so – no joy. I stopped and started the Wi-Fi (both 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz) – no joy. I changed the Wi-Fi passwords... you get the drift.

The first router that was borked this way was a NetGear; this one is a TP-Link. Both are consumer grade. What do you suggest?

Comment: This site breakdown is getting way too confusing. I've been following StackOverflow on and off since what seems like forever, and I've consistently been participating as long as my time permitted. But even so – admittedly only as a sort of an external enthusiast – this is not the first time I miss the mark and apparently ask a question on the wrong website. And I find this concerning. A person who's actively trying to ask their question in the right forum and repeatedly fails to do so is not an indication of that person's idiocy, but rather of the website's inability to direct people properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The router is surely dead for the WiFi, please try another's one. Maybe use a UPS to protect your network gear.

Comment: Yep, you're right – the WiFi module seems dead for good. I'm not sure a full-on UPS is needed, but at the very least a surge-protected plug would probably have done the trick. (In my case, a few extra neurons would've sufficed – I only had to unplug the whole shebang, which I obviously didn't.)